# C++ get window handle from device context

Tags: c++, window, handle

I have been trying to get the handle to a window though a device context handle. I've tried WindowFromDC() and its constantly returning null results. How can I get the window handle from any device context?

Comment: Where is the DC coming from? if its returning nothing could it be a memory DC?

Answer (score 6):

All people know how get the handle of DC but nobody know how retrieve the handle of the corresponding windows ?

Try this :

```
HWnd = WindowFromDC(HDc)
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-windowfromdc

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is no window belonging to this DC.

> If no window is associated with the specified DC, the return value is NULL.

You could for instance create an offscreen bitmap (without window) and get a DC for it. Then this DC would have no window.

Comment: Almost all of the results are null, so I could not tell the difference between desktop and the app's own dcs

Comment: And I know its getting the dc of the desktop. hwnd of desktop is not null.

Answer (score -2):

```
HDC hdc;               // display device context handle  


// Retrieve a handle identifying the private DC.  

hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162744(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is the reverse of what is being asked.